# Access different Webcams via v4l2src with same command

Tags: usb, webcam, udev

I try to access changing usb cameras connected to my only usb port on my system running Ubuntu 20.04.

My command is:

**gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src device=/dev/video13 !**

As always, the path is changing after every boot.

I can connect to one specific usb camera everytime with:

**gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src device=/dev/v4l/by-id/usb-5M_Camera_5M_Camera_5M_Camera-video-index0**

but I`m using different usb camera models and my system should connect without user interaction.

I tried my luck with

***gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src  device=/dev/v4l/by-id/find *index0 !****

because every connected usb camera appears in that folder and shows 2 files, where index0 is the working one.

But that command doesn't work and I seems pure wildcards like

gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src  device=/dev/v4l/by-id/ ****index0 !***

wont work either...

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu, just a hint as I can't test at the moment :). `head` with 1 line filter of (`ls` with first sorting newer of (odd `/dev/video*[13579]` devices) should bring you last plugged video device to use with `gst-launch-1.0` command.